# Accessing private members of a class from another class

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, class-design

I have 3 classes

```
class A {
    B *b;
}

class B {
C *c
}

class C {
....
}
```

What is the best way to access instance of class C inside class B from class A? Please also suggest a way to write the constructor for each of these classes?

Comment: Rethink what you want here. Do you want them to be private, or do you want other classes to touch them directly? The 2 are contradictory. If you want these members to be public though, just write the classes in the opposite order.

Comment: If member are private, you should not access them. make them public or create public accessors.

Comment: given the information you provide, the least overcomplicated solution is to make the member `public`. For anything else you need to consider what `A`,`B` and `C` really is, how they are related and why `c` was declared `private` in the first place

Comment: The easiest and perhaps the fastest way is to use the 'friend' keyword.

Comment: Look, this can be done, as others have mentioned, with 'friend', or a function giving you a pointer to a private member, or some such.  But if you have to do this, you need to rethink your class design.  This is not a good idea -- if it were, there would be no need for private members!  In other words, you can do this, but you shouldn't want to :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple possibilities to access members of other classes.

If a member is private (as in your case) you can either declare other classes as a friend of this class or write getters and setters.

**Method 1: Getters and Setters**

```
class A {
private: 
  int a;
public:
  int GetA() { return a; }
  void SetA(int newA) { a = newA; }
};
```

This however will grant access to your private data from every other place in your code. Though you can leave `setA` away causing only read access to the private `a`.

---

*Edit*:

As @tobi303 has correctly pointed out: Returning a raw pointer via a getter (as it would be in your case) is probably not a good idea. So I would recommend in this case to either return the object the pointer points to or use smart pointers like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and return them:

```
class {
private:
  int *a;
  std::shared_ptr<int> b;
public:
  int getA() { return a ? *a : 0; } // only dereference the pointer if it points somewhere
  std::shared_ptr<const int> getB() { return b; } // return as std::shared_ptr<const int> to prevent indirect write access to a
};
```

---

**Method 2: Friend Classes**

```
class B
{};

class A {
private: 
  int a;
public: 
  friend class B;
};
```

In this case only `B` and `A` can access the private data of `A`. You can also grant access to the private data to only a few functions.

However, granting write access to private members often indicates a flaw in your design. Maybe they should be public (see Method 3) or you don't even need write access and just reading them would be completely sufficient for your needs.

**Method 3: Public Members**

```
class A {
public:
  int a;
};
```

Similar to Method 1 (with both the getter and the setter) you are now granting read and write access to `A`s member `a`.

If you really need read and write access to a private member, Method 2 is the way to go. But as I've said: Think about your design once again, do you really need this?

Comment: imho your example doesnt fit perfectly. Returning an `int` via a getter is almost never a problem, however returning a raw pointer (that actually was supposed to be private) is rather questionable

Comment: @tobi303 Right, haven't realised that the OP uses pointers in his example. I provided an example using pointers for Method 1.

Comment: @Shyam Ask a new question rather than editing your question and making it completely different.